# encrypted data in Javascript is not being decrypted with php properly

Tags: javascript, php, encryption, mcrypt, cryptojs

I am encrypting with Cryptojs in javascript with this function.

```
  function encode(text, skey) {
    var base64Iv = "0123456789abcdef";
    var key = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse(skey);
    var iv = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse(base64Iv);
    var encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(text), key, {iv: iv, mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC, padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7});
    var encryptedData = encrypted.toString();
    return encryptedData;   
}
```

and trying to decrypt it with php_mcrypt with this function

```
    function decrypt($crypt, $key, $type){
      $enc = MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128;
      $mode = MCRYPT_MODE_CBC;
      $iv = "0123456789abcdef";
      $crypt = base64_decode($crypt);
      $padtext = mcrypt_decrypt($enc, base64_decode($key) , $crypt, $mode, $iv);
      echo ("PADTEXT"+$padtext);
      $pad = ord($padtext
        {
        strlen($padtext) - 1});
        if ($pad > strlen($padtext)) return false;
        if (strspn($padtext, $padtext{ strlen($padtext) - 1}, strlen($padtext) - $pad) != $pad)
                {
                $text = "Error";
                }

            $text = substr($padtext, 0, -1 * $pad);
            echo ("TEXT "+$text);
            return $text;
}
```

I am using the same key and iv however it is not decrypting the beginning of string properly.

**Expected Result:**
00paygate|201710270001|12345|16|USD|INR|SALE|http://localhost/Response.php|http://localhost/Response.php|WEB

**Actual Result:**
00�-ܗ�ڀ��x��RTWQ0001|12345|16|USD|INR|SALE|http://localhost/Response.php|http://localhost/Response.php|WEB

Comment: Why use encryption in javascript, where your key is easily visible, instead of simple https?

Comment: Your IV logic makes no sense.  Why are you decoding the IV from base64 if it **isn't** base64?  Fix this in your JavaScript first.